# Is there a way to download Windows games on Steam but for my Macbook Pro?

Tags: steam, macos, windows

I have a Macbook Pro and all my friends have 40+ games but most of them are for Windows. So is there anyway that I can download them but on my Mac and be able to play them?

Comment: I'm confused. Are you asking if you can download the Windows version of the game on your Mac? I believe this is possible, but you won't be able to play it while running OSX. Are you asking if you can download the Mac versions of the game? Yes, assuming you have steam installed and it does in fact have a mac version.

Comment: Ok originaluser I just thought there might be a way to!

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking if you can play *Windows Only* games on your Mac then your only option is to use Bootcamp to install Windows on your Mac and then boot your Mac into Windows instead of OSX.

If you choose this, you can still have OSX too. You would hold the option button on startup and and it would ask you if you would like to boot Windows or OSX. Googling 'How to dual boot Windows on Macbook' should help you do this. You will also need a copy of windows to install on your Macbook Pro